# Python script to move data from a SQL server db to an oracle db keeps giving 'ORA-01036: illegal variable name/number'

Tags: python, sql, oracle

So I am using python to pull data from a sql server with a simple select that grabs 15 columns. The data looks like this

```
2016-06-01 05:45:06.003,5270,240,1,1,0,5000,1,null,null,7801009661561,0,null,null,null
```

The columns on the oracle table are all number except for the first column which is date. The sizes are all correct.

After I get all the data i run it through this little function to get rid of the pyodbc.row types.

```
def BuildBindList(recordsToWrite):
    closingRecords = []
    for rec in recordsToWrite:
        closingRecords.append((rec[0], rec[1], rec[2], rec[3], rec[4],  rec[5], rec[6], rec[7], rec[7], rec[8], rec[9], rec[10], rec[11], rec[12], rec[13], rec[14]))
    return closingRecords
```

I get a list of tuples.

Then to write to the oracle table I wrote this function that takes in the list of tuples.

```
    def write_to_table(recordsToWrite):     
        SQL = '''INSERT INTO ####### (DATETIME, ID, TZ, DOMAINID, EVENTNAME, REASONCODE, TARGETID, STATE, KEY, PERIPHERALKEY, RECOVERYKEY, DIRECTION, ROUTERDAY, ROUTERCKEY, ROUTERNUMBER)
                VALUES(:1, :2, :3, :4, :5, :6, :7, :8, :9, :10, :11, :12, :13, :14, :15)'''
        try:
            trgtcrsr.prepare(SQL)
        except cx_Oracle.DatabaseError, exception:
            print ('Failed to prepare cursor')
            print Exception(exception)
            exit (1)
        try:
            trgtcrsr.executemany(None, recordsToWrite)        
        except cx_Oracle.DatabaseError, exception:
            print ('Failed to insert rows')
            print Exception(exception)
            exit (1)
        target_connection .commit()
        target_connection .close()
```

I make the oracle connection like this

```
try:
    cnn = cx_Oracle.connect(user="####", password = "####", dsn = "####")
    trgtcrsr = cnn.cursor()
    print "Connected to Oracle"
except Exception as e:
    print e
    raise RuntimeError("Could not connect to Oracle")
```

The connection works fine. But when the line `trgtcrsr.executemany(None, recordsToWrite)` is executed it gives me a `'ORA-01036: illegal variable name/number'` error

I have another script that uses the same method of writing a list of tuples to an oracle table with the `trgtcrsr.prepare(SQL)`/`trgtcrsr.executemany(None, recordsToWrite)` method and it works fine (granted its oracle to oracle) writing to oracle so I am not sure why I keep getting this error. I have tried changing data types and googling the error but cant find anything similar.

Any ideas?

Comment: What are the values of the record, that fail to insert?

Comment: @Daniel It doesn't tell me.

Comment: @bernie Isn't a list of tuples a container of tuples?

Comment: so you have to output debug information, e.g calling `execute` instead of `executemany`, so you know, which record fails.

Comment: `#######` isn't a valid table name.

Comment: @JohnGordon you are very right. But the table name contains identifying information that i am not including which is why you get a `########`

Comment: This link talks about that error and archivelog mode: http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_ora_01036_exp_illegal_name_number.htm . If it's related to running out of allocated space, you could do a trial to see if your import completes for a much smaller number of rows.

Comment: You have rec[7] twice in the bind list.. might be a mismatch in column count.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`rec[7]` appears twice in the function `BuildBindList()`.

I'm guessing this will cause the insert to fail as you passed it 16 columns to instantiate 15 bind variables in the `insert` statement.

Comment: I feel super dumb that I didn't notice that. Thank you very much this fixed the problem.

Answer (score 1):

```
**#PYTHON SCRIPT TO COPY DATA FROM ORACLE TO SQL SERVER**
    import cx_Oracle 
    import pyodbc 
#Server Variables
    orServer = '10.xxx.x.xxx'
    orPort = 'xxxx'
    orService = 'MYSERV'
    orUser = 'ORMYUSER'
    orPassword = 'orpassword'
    sqlServer = 'SQLSERVER'
    sqlDatabase = 'MYDB'
#SQL Server Connection
    sqlConn = pyodbc.connect('Driver={SQL Server};'
                      'Server='+sqlServer+';'
                      'Database='+sqlDatabase+';'
                      'Trusted_Connection=yes;')
    sqlCursor = sqlConn.cursor()

#Oracle Connection
    dsn_tns = cx_Oracle.makedsn(orServer, orPort, service_name= orService ) 
    orConn = cx_Oracle.connect(user= orUser, password= orPassword, dsn=dsn_tns) 
    orCursor = orConn.cursor()

#Get data from Oracle Server
    orCursor.execute("""SELECT  ID
                                ,NAME
                                ,SEX
                                ,ADDRESS
                                PHONE
                        FROM DetailsTable"""
                    )

    orColumns =['ID',
                'NAME',
                'SEX',
                'ADDRESS',
                'PHONE']

#Creating Strings for insert statement to load data into SQL Server
    cValues = str(orColumns).replace("[","(").replace("]",")").replace("'","")

    x = len(orColumns) 

    i = 0

    ab = []

    while i < x:
        i = i+ 1
        ab.append("?")

    values = str(ab).replace("[","(").replace("]",")").replace("'","")

#Load data to SQL server
    sqlCursor.executemany("INSERT INTO [MYDB].[dbo].[DetailsTable]"+ cValues+ " VALUES "+ values ,orCursor)
    sqlConn.commit()
    sqlConn.close()
    orConn.close()
```